# Working with Symfony and Git (collaboration)

Tags: git, symfony1, repository-pattern, collaboration, git-submodules

Suppose we have a Project with three applications — A, B and C. Our 
team: Jack, Susan and Martin. And one project leader — David.

Each programmer is working on their own application:

> A - Jack
>
> B - Susan
>
> C - Martin

So, there is a problem with source code management. How to effectively 
organize it with Git? I have several use-cases, but I'm not really 
sure if they are correct and effective. Here they are:

1. One repo for whole project.
2. Separate repositories for A, B and
   C apps (within their  appropriate
   directories in "apps" folder).

I really like second idea, but I'm not if it's really effective.

What do you thing and how would you organize such things? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why use Git for this instead of Subversion?

Comment: @Coronatus It's a choice of favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The answer is — [Git Submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html).

Answer (score 1):

This all comes down to how tightly coupled those applications are. If they have dependencies amongst them (A calls private, still-changing APIs of B and C), then putting them in one repository would make sense. If they are developed independently, then they should be in separate repositories.

Comment: Thanks @Novelocrat. The highest dependency would be if i.e. A shows some of the symfony components from B or C...